# Edge Extension does not respond to runtime.onMessage.addListener()

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, browser-extension

I have been trying to get my hands dirty with developing some extensions on the Edge platform. Going good so far, until I hit a blocker. I have a method in my background script which produces context menus, and when clicked, sends a message to the context script. Everything works fine except that the context script shows no signs of invoking the event listener.

Here is my code:
manifest.json:

```
{
"name":"Edge",
"author":"Auth",
"version":"1.0",
"description":"none",
"permissions":["*://*/","tabs","bookmarks","unlimitedStorage","contextMenus"],
"browser_action":{
    "default_icon":{
        "20":"images/Edge.png",
        "40":"images/Edge40.png"
    },
    "default_title":"Edge"
},
"background":{
    "persistent":true,
    "scripts":["back.js"]

},
"content_scripts":[{
    "matches":["<all_urls>"],
    "js":["cs.js"],
    "run_at":"document_end"
}]
```

}

background script:

```
browser.contextMenus.create({
id: "Show Notes",
title: "Show Notes",
contexts: ['link']
});

browser.contextMenus.create({
    id:"Make Notes",
    title:"Make Notes",
    contexts:['all']
});


browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    alert("s")
    alert(info.menuItemId)
    alert(info.linkUrl)
    browser.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs){
        browser.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){
            browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{
                "id":info.menuItemId,
                "link":info.linkUrl
            })
        })
    }) 
    alert("sent")
});
```

Content script:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(lis)

function lis(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("msg")
    if(request.id=="Show Notes"){
        alert("received")
        note.style.display="block"
    }
    if(request.id=="Make Notes"){
        note.style.display="block"
        alert("received")
    }
    return true
}
```

All the alert messages in the background script work fine, but the content script just doesn't make even a single pop up.

I have read and tried to implement a lot of answers, not of them worked.
What could be going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Edge probably just like Chrome doesn't inject content scripts right after you install or reload your extension so you need to refresh the web page(s) or run the content script manually in all tabs using browser.tabs.executeScript

Comment: Done that, no use. I could see the injected code in the Dev tools debugger section.  So, is browser.tabs.execute the only solution?

Comment: The funny part is message passing from content script to background script works just fine.

Comment: Why would you use :::

tabs.getCurrent when tabs.query({active: true}) will return the active tab. You can use either of them as they both return the same thing. Also you can add "currentWindow : true" to get active tab from current browser window. Edge is notoriously buggy currently so I would suggest you to recreate a new tab to work with content scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Edge doesn't support Promises, you would have to rely on callback mechanism. Please synchronize your `tabs.query` or `tabs.getCurrent` with `tabs.sendMessage`. For the given code you will be seeing an error in the background page's console stating "id as undefined". Synchronizing the above two methods would help fix this. Also the `bookmark` permission in the `manifest.json` is useless as Edge currently doesn't support bookmarks. (Just wanted you to know this incase you missed it).